# How do weights work in an Artificial Neural Network for Prediction?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Suppose i have 4 input data set.
I am trying to implement an artificial neural network like the diagram below.
[image]

After training the neurons,i get 10 weights. How do i use these 10 weights to predict on test data?.

```
(n X 4) -> Test Data (A)
(10 X 1) -> Trained Weights (w)
(n X 4) (4 X 1) -> Predicted Output (How are the weights used here?)
```

Aw = y
Where A is my test data and w is my weights, y is the predicted output.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by converges to 4 weights, but for the 'prediction' part you simply feed the network with your inputs and calculate the outputs by simple arithmetics. Neural networks are maps from inputs to outputs, so 4 input will yield 1 output in your case. If I get you, it wont work as you expect; to get 4 weights and map the 4 inputs to 4 outputs you will need 4 outputs too, and one neuron connected to only one.

Comment: If i understand correctly i need to use the test data in a feed forward neural network with the new wights.

Comment: I think you misunderstood how neural networks work. This is a very good tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16419/AI-Neural-Network-for-beginners-Part-of by training the nn you change its structure to fit your test data, by 'prediction' you use the modified structure to calculate the output the same way as you calculated during the training, but you don't modify it now - btw its not an exact definition.

Comment: Ah thanks. This make sense.

Comment: I make a little answer from comment, accept it if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how neural networks work. This is a very good tutorial explaining this from the beginning: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16419/AI-Neural-Network-for-beginners-Part-of)

In short: By training the neural network **you change its structure to fit your test data**, by *prediction* you use the modified structure to calculate the output the same way as you calculated during the training, but you don't modify it now.